# how to use "npx create-expo-app" if npm said: "The system cannot find the specified path"?

Tags: reactjs, npm, expo, version, npx

After expo migrates from "expo start" to "npx expo start" i am trying to set dependencies and run my react project. With no sucess i am trying to start a new project with all enviroment new and updated. So, when i put: "npx create-expo-app --template" on terminal, the prompt answer me: The system cannot find the specified path.

But, when i try the old way, using: "expo init" the process starts correctly.

How to use new version of expo if the enviroment isnt ready, yet?

I am trying to keep developing a react project without figth against versions